# How to bind element once?

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind item to the view only once in my angulajs project.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4n9yxyHZJnEonqzkcOf1?p=preview).

Here the template html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <span ng-repeat="city in ma.cities" class="view" ng-if="city.Id == ma.selected">
             {{::city.Name}}
     </span>

    <select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="ma.selected" 
    ng-options="city.Id as city.Name for city in ma.cities">

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the city.Name to be bind to template html only once.
But the problem that when  I change the item in select element the city.Name is also updated.

I try to use once bind operator `::`  but it didn't help.

How can I bind element to the view only once and to prevent update?

Comment: `ng-repeat="city in ::ma.cities"`

Answer (score 2):

The value isn't changing. You're got an ng-if nested within an ng-repeat and when the city is changed which item is displayed changes.

If I'm following what you're trying to do, I would store the currently selected city to a property on the controller when the controller is created and display that property, eliminating the ng-repeat and the ng-if in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **Mike**, the question is a bit ambiguous. I think what you're asking for is:

```
<span>{{::ma.cities[ma.selected].Name}}</span>
```

But then again, as **Mike** said, you could've achieved that with another scope variable, and it would be probably a much clearer solution.

Comment: What if instead of selected index I have selected Id?

Comment: That's why **Mike**'s approach is better. You really should handle this in the controller. If you have *Id* only, you'll have to iterate over your cities and find the city by your selected Id.

Answer (score 0):

As YOU adviced I modified html template:

```
 <span ng-repeat="city in ::ma.cities" class="view" ng-if="::city.Id == ma.selectedId">
                 {{city.Name}}
         </span>
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IqkZEIvQFSn9oIRS9Sfc?p=info).